# (Android 4.2.2) Sync my contact photos with Facebook?

Tags: contacts, facebook, contact-photo

I'd like to add a contact picture to all of my contacts, but when I first installed Facebook I synced my phone to all of my Facebook friends. I quickly realized this was a mistake as I then had loads of contacts I didn't want, so I removed the Facebook account, and uninstalled the Facebook app. I then re installed the app and this time clicked "sync only my contacts", but this again synced with all of my Facebook friends.

If I change the settings to show only the contacts on my sim then I'm back to square one, and none of the contacts have pictures.

How can I resolve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the app "Sync ME", it saves the contact pics of your Facebook Friends to your contacts.

Answer (score 1):

I have used Haxsync previously.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mots.haxsync

There is also an xposed module which I now use instead, called XFBSync. This does all that Facebook used to by itself, like syncs profile photos, and phone numbers.

If you are able I would give that a go.